# Regex for alpha component or RGBA/HSLA, why I'm getting matching groups?

Tags: php, regex, alpha, pcre, rgba

```
^(?:(?:0(:?\.[0-9])?)|(?:1(?:\.0)?))$
```

*Should (i'm not a regex guru)* match the alpha component of RGBA/HSLA (`0`, `0.0 to 0.9`, `1`, `1.0`).

However when I use [Rubular with this regex/test string](http://rubular.com/r/U8GmfscInf) I get a matching group of `1.` with test string `1.0` and I get a matching group `.9` with test string `0.9`.

I don't need to capture groups... what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: paranthesis makes groups themselves.

Comment: @davidkonrad yes, but as I said I'm not very good at regex. Is there a way to get the same result without groups?

Comment: you could try with `?=` instead of `?:` - positive lookahead. What about an example string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting groups for this:

```
^(?:(?:0(:?\.[0-9])?)|(?:1(?:\.0)?))$
         ^^ its a mistake i believe
```

It should be:

```
^(?:(?:0(?:\.[0-9])?)|(?:1(?:\.0)?))$
         ^^
```

`:?` means optional colon. So it always matches with your input. Whereas `?:` means ignore group capture, which you are already using.

Comment: I guess I'm stupid, you're perfectly right. Thanks for getting into the solution!